# How does input buffering work in C++

Tags: c++, inputstream, input-buffer

Here is a code snippet. I'm confused as to how the buffering internally works.

```
  while(true)
  {
      cout << "Enter a character: ";
      cin.ignore(3, '\n');
      ch = cin.get();  // ch is char type
      cout << "char: ch: " << ch << endl;
  }
```

Actually `cin.ignore(3, '\n')` ignores the first three characters and then gets the next immediate character. Till that point its fine. Since, I kept this in a `while` loop, I was trying to check the behavior of `ignore()` and `get()`. For instance, the output for which I checked was

```
Enter a character: abcd
char: ch: d
Enter a character: efgh
char: ch: e
Enter a character: ijkl
char: ch: i
Enter a character: mnopq
char: ch: m
Enter a character: char: ch: q
Enter a character:
```

Just to check the buffering, intentionally I was give 4 characters instead of 1. In the first case, its fine and got it. From second, the ignore doesn't seem to work. When I entered 5 characters, I din't get the behavior.

Need explanation on this. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation of std::cin.ignore(streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF):

> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim.
>   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

You are putting `abcd\n` onto stdin. Your first `ignore(3,'\n')` removes `abc` and your get() fetches `d`. `\n` remains in the buffer.

Then you add `efgh\n` to the buffer which now contains `\nefgh\n`. Your next ignore() reads **either** 3 characters or a newline, whatever comes first. Since your newline is first in the buffer, only the newline is ignored.

You probably want to empty the stdin buffer before asking for more input. You can achieve this either by modifying your get() call, or by adding a second ignore() call before asking for more input.

Comment: How does one flush an input stream?

Comment: Sorry, bad use of language. I mean that the input buffer needs to be emptied before asking for more input.

Answer (score 2):

`cin.ignore(3, '\n')` ignores *up to* three characters, stopping after it finds the end of a line (i.e. a `\n` character).

After the first line of input, the buffer will contain 5 characters, `abcd\n`. So `ignore` ignores `abc`, and `get` gets `d`, leaving `\n`.

After the second line, it contains `\nefgh\n`. So `ignore` just ignores the end-of-line character, and `get` returns `e`.

If you want to discard the rest of line after extracting the character, then use `ignore` again:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Discard in the sense, it will be still there in that input stream right ? If so, how do we clear it ?

Comment: @Chaitanya: Discard in the sense of removing it from the input stream, which is what `ignore` does.